# Plotting of functions Using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to plot the graphs using PSTricks. I am using Miktex+Texmaker with the configurations-LeTeX+dvips+ps2pdf+ View PDF. have the following latex commands/codes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{pst-math}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \scalebox{1.1}{
    \psset{unit=2.5cm} % Adjust the unit size as needed
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
      \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20]
      \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3) % Corrected line
      \psplot{0}{5}{sqrt(x)}
      \psplot[linecolor=red]{-5}{5}{ATAN(x)}
    \end{pspicture}
  }
  \caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I compile, the picture doesn't appear though there is no errors appearing. Please help me troubleshoot.

Comment: ps2pdf shows a postscript error `Error: /typecheck in --mul-- Operand stack:   0.0   (x)   71.1319` meaning you are trying to multiply 0 bythe string `x`

Comment: `\psplot` requires a function in PostScript syntax. Look into the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/doc/pst-plot-doc.pdf) for more information. You need to replace `sqrt(x)` by `x sqrt` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find it easier to use pgfplots (tikz pased) rather than pstricks unless you are happy to write the functions in postscript. `x sqrt` for example,  arctan perhaps as below (see comments for help given on atan)  although that isn't quite the form I expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{pst-math}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \scalebox{1.1}{
    \psset{unit=2.5cm} % Adjust the unit size as needed
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
      \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20]
      \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3) % Corrected line
      \psplot{0}{5}{x sqrt}
      \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{5}{x 1 atan 3.14159 mul 180 div}
      \psplot[linecolor=red]{-5}{0}{x -1 atan 3.14159 mul -180 div 3.14159 add}
    \end{pspicture}
  }
  \caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, `\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{5}{x 1 atan 3.14159 mul 180 div} \psplot[linecolor=red]{-5}{0}{x -1 atan 3.14159 mul -180 div 3.14159 add}` would output the expected plot (you need to convert degrees to radians). (But I don't quite get, why you need to add pi to the negative part.)

Comment: @JasperHabicht thanks, updated

Answer (score 5):

The option `algebraic` can be used to write normal expression.
The option `plotpoint` can be used for better precision.

`ATAN` is the name of the function in radian

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \scalebox{1.1}{
    \psset{unit=2.5cm} % Adjust the unit size as needed
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
      \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20]
      \psaxes[showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3) %showorigin=false to not dispaly "0" on axes 
            \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=200]{0}{3}{sqrt(x)} %algebraic for classical expression and plotpoints=200 for more précisions
            \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=200]{-3}{3}{ATAN(x)}
    \end{pspicture}
  }
  \caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For information it also works with lualatex

Comment: My favourite answer, +1

Answer (score 3):

`pst-algparser.pro` defines function `atg` which outputs the angle in radians. Also it defines `AlgParser` that allows for algebraic (infix) notation as input. Input is a string , `(...<infix input>...)`, and output is an array with PostScript commands that needs to be made executable (`cvx`) and finally executed `exec`:

```
\psplot[linecolor=red]{-5}{5}{(atg(x)) AlgParser cvx exec}
```

The PostScript built-in `atan` is difficult to be used (see David's answer) as it wants two arguments as input, a
fraction consisting of the tangens value itself and a divisor, and it returns an angle in **degrees**. The fraction input allows for infinity as input:

```
1 0 atan => 90
```

To use the PostScript `atan` in **infix** notation, the following plot command would produce the expected graph:

```
\psplot[linecolor=red]{-5}{5}{(DegtoRad(-atan(x,-1))+Pi) AlgParser cvx exec}
```

---

With `atg`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{pst-math}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \scalebox{1.1}{
    \psset{unit=2.5cm} % Adjust the unit size as needed
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
      \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20]
      \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3) % Corrected line
      \psplot{0}{5}{(sqrt(x)) AlgParser cvx exec}
      \psplot[linecolor=red]{-5}{5}{(atg(x)) AlgParser cvx exec}
    \end{pspicture}
  }
  \caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run with `lualatex`:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\psset{unit=1.5cm} % Adjust the unit size as needed
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20]
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3) % Corrected line
    \psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt]{0}{3}{sqrt(x)}
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-3}{3}{ATAN(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The graph $G_1$}\label{Fig-2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]