# Plot the graph of sin-cos functions using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, function

I have the following codes in Miktex+Texmaker using the configurations LaTeX+dvips+ps2pdf+View PDF:

The following first figure (`fig:cosine-plot`) appears clearly:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(4,1.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.5)(4,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=red, algebraic]{-2}{3.5}{cos(x)}
  \end{pspicture}
  \caption{Plot of $\cos(x)$}
  \label{fig:cosine-plot}
\end{figure}
```

However, the following second figure (`Fig-sin-cos`) doesn't appear on the compilation.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(4,1.5)
    \psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20]
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.5)(4,1.5)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2}{4}{sin(x)}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-2}{4}{cos(x)}
  \end{pspicture}
  \caption{Graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$}\label{Fig-sin-cos}
\end{figure}
```

Please help me plot the second Graphs of `\sin(x)` and `\cos(x)`.

The related question has the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708372/plotting-of-functions-using-pstricks).

Comment: this is identical to your last question. where you had `sqrt(x)` instead of `x sqrt`  and now you have `cos(x)` instead of `x cos` or as shown in the other answer to your last question you can use the pstricks algebraic function parser, or (like most people) you could use pdflatex instead of latex/dvips/pstopdf and use pgfplots rather than pstricks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: you can also use `xelatex`  or better `lualatex` to get direct the pdf output.

Comment: @user187802 yes true

Answer (score 2):

You need the option `algebraic`, you can do it globaly with `\psset{algebraic}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
 
\psset{algebraic} %change
\begin{figure}[ht] 
\centering 
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5)(4,1.5) 
\psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black!20] 
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.5)(4,1.5) 
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2}{4}{sin(x)} 
\psplot[linecolor=red]{-2}{4}{cos(x)} 
\end{pspicture} 
\caption{Graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$}\label{Fig-sin-cos} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```